# replace special characters along with the space in list of strings

Tags: string, r, special-characters, whitespace

I have character vector of strings like this :

```
x <- c("weather is good_today","it. will rain tomorrow","do not* get_angry")
```

I want to replace all the special characters and space and replace them with "_".
I used `str_replace all` from the `stringr package` like this :

```
x1 <- str_replace_all(x,"[[:punct:]]","_")
x2 <- str_replace_all(x1,"\\s+","_")
```

But can this be done in one single command and I can get the output like this :

```
x
[1]"weather_is_good_today"
[2]"it_will_rain_tomorrow"
[3]"do_not_get_angry"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can I ask why you want it in one command?

Comment: @agstudy, put it back up.  It should have been an answer anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this .

```
x1 <- str_replace_all(x,"[[:punct:]\\\s]+","_")
```

I don't have knowledge in R , i suggested the answer based on Regular expression checked with[Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing#Regular_Expressions)

Comment: This answer is actually inaccurate. While "str_replace_all" is a nice function, the actual regexpr should be ([[:punct:]])|\\s+)

Answer (score 25):

```
 gsub('([[:punct:]])|\\s+','_',x)

"weather_is_good_today"  "it__will_rain_tomorrow" "do_not__get_angry"
```